# How to setup the cores of driver in spark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am using the client deploy model with spark standalone from Jupyter notebook. My configure in the application is like:

```
conf.setMaster('spark://hadoop-master:7077')
conf.set("spark.driver.cores","4")
conf.set("spark.driver.memory","8g")
conf.set("spark.executor.memory","16g")
```

But, I speculated that spark.driver.cores was not working, the Spark WEB UI shown:
[image]

Why is the cores zero? How to modify this value?
Additionally, the Environment of Spark WEB UI showed, like:
[image]

So, the config seemly has uploaded to the server.

Comment: How many cores do you have in sum in your machine?

Comment: My machine is a server of 16 cores. I made 4 virtual machines on this server. There are 4 cores per virtual machine.

Comment: From screens it seems that the slave services not included and the executor only remains driver node.

Comment: My application can execute on the slave and driver, like reading file from Hadoop, showing of Dataframe, but did not run this join operation.

Comment: could you paste code snippet where included DF and the join